# VTK: how can I add a scrollbar to my project?

Tags: vtk

What's the easiest way to add a scrollbar to my VTK project ?

thanks

Update

```
def vtkSliderCallback2(obj, event):
    sliderRepres = obj.GetRepresentation()
    pos = sliderRepres.GetValue()
    contourFilter.SetValue(0, pos)

SliderRepres = vtk.vtkSliderRepresentation2D()
min = 0 #ImageViewer.GetSliceMin()
max = 256 #ImageViewer.GetSliceMax()
SliderRepres.SetMinimumValue(min)
SliderRepres.SetMaximumValue(max)
SliderRepres.SetValue((min + max) / 2)
SliderRepres.SetTitleText("Slice")
SliderRepres.GetPoint1Coordinate().SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedDisplay()
SliderRepres.GetPoint1Coordinate().SetValue(0.2, 0.6)
SliderRepres.GetPoint2Coordinate().SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedDisplay()
SliderRepres.GetPoint2Coordinate().SetValue(0.4, 0.6)

SliderRepres.SetSliderLength(0.02)
SliderRepres.SetSliderWidth(0.03)
SliderRepres.SetEndCapLength(0.01)
SliderRepres.SetEndCapWidth(0.03)
SliderRepres.SetTubeWidth(0.005)
SliderRepres.SetLabelFormat("%3.0lf")
SliderRepres.SetTitleHeight(0.02)
SliderRepres.SetLabelHeight(0.02)

SliderWidget = vtk.vtkSliderWidget()
SliderWidget.SetInteractor(iren)
SliderWidget.SetRepresentation(SliderRepres)
SliderWidget.KeyPressActivationOff()
SliderWidget.SetAnimationModeToAnimate()
SliderWidget.SetEnabled(True)
SliderWidget.AddObserver("InteractionEvent", vtkSliderCallback2)
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881863/vtk-how-can-i-a-scrollbar-widget

Comment: @bastijn ups I forgot. I deleted the previous one.

Comment: can you post some more information, what do you need it for? Usually you do not make scrollbars with VTK but with the language you use around it.

Comment: @bastijn, I need to set a value. So it should work as input widget. I've seen I can use entry widget combined with the scrollbar for this. But I'm looking for the exact code.

Comment: To set a value? Like vtkSliderWidget does :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be complete and for other users googling thing.

vtkSliderWidget will do what you want if you need it to set a value.

//edit based on your edit 
If you want to get the value, you have to connect an event to the slider which is fired when the value is changed. Than retrieve this value and update accordingly. An example in C++ is found [here](http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Examples/Widgets/Cxx/Slider2D.cxx)

***// I actually think my issue is that the callback function is invoked for each thumb position when I slide it. How can avoid that ? In other words I only want the last position to trigger the callback function...***

Try coupling it to the EndInteractionEvent instead of to the InteractionEvent.

```
SliderWidget.AddObserver("EndInteractionEvent", vtkSliderCallback2)
```

// stuff

By the way, if you use python and VTK and need GUI stuff, I advice you to use the python QT and python qt widgets which ease up alot of this stuff. Some code of one of my old projects using QT+Python+VTK for GUI + python stuff:

```
self.verticalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
self.verticalSlider.setObjectName("verticalSlider")
self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.verticalSlider)

// connect slider to a method onValueChange
QObject.connect(self.verticalSlider, SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), 
self.setFibreVolumeOpacity)

def setFibreVolumeOpacity(self, value):
    // do stuff here with slider value.
```

Comment: Ok.. one last thing: I dunno how to get the current value of the slider.. (right after an interaction).. thanks

Comment: can you update the question with your programming language and the full code (init stuff for your slider) ? Than we can have a better look.

Comment: I've update it. I actually think my issue is that the callback function is invoked for each thumb position when I slide it. How can avoid that ? In other words I only want the last position to trigger the callback function...

Comment: Couple it to the EndInteractionEvent instead of the InteractionEvent only.